# Searching for an element with an dynamic xpath using selenium with python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-chromedriver

How can I find this `xpath... //*[@id="hand_1308744119"]` using Selenium.

The `1308744119` is dynamic the only thing constant is hand_ in each element's xpath.

I tried..

```
xelem=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='hand_']")
xelem=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[id$=hand_]")
```

but no luck!

Comment: can you so html so we can understand easily

Comment: <span id="hand_1334530584" link="http://www.etplnetwork.com/rf-optimization/" class="handIcon" onclick="updateTask(1334530584,this)"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up custom"></i></span>

Comment: this is the element i need to catch, but these elements have changing xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't ever used selenium on python, but xpath's should act the same across all languages.

You'll want to use "contains" in your xpath. It'll tell the xpath that you want to find an element that contains what you want. Right now you are telling the xpath is has to be 'hand_'.

Something like the below - this is telling the xpath that you want to find an element where the @id contains 'hand_':

```
xelem=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'hand_')]")
```

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting? The method you are using returns a list of elements, not one. Are you trying to do actions on a list of elements (you can't)? The way I mentioned before should work. 

You could also try:

xelem=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'hand')]")

Comment: just fetchin the list and printing the elements. no actions

Comment: And it is saying that no elements have been found?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the find element call is being executed too early - before the elements are created. You might have to implement a wait. Otherwise, it'll return nothing if find element is called before the elements have loaded on the page.

Comment: thanks Brian, you were right. a little delay fixed it.